# Problems with using JADE and Excel

Tags: java, excel, multithreading, agents-jade

1. I am working with JADE and I want Agents to write some information in am excel file. what is wrong with my code that as I debug I receive the error: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0` at line `MASTER1.write();` what is wrong with it?..

here is code:

```
public class TryBehaviours extends Agent {
@Override
protected void setup(){

    System.out.println("Agent" + this.getLocalName() + " Says: Hellowww" );

    addBehaviour(new DataStore(this));

}
public class DataStore extends OneShotBehaviour{

    public DataStore(Agent a) {
        super(a);
    }


    @Override
    public void action() {
        try {
            File f;
            f = new File ("C:\\Users\\MR\\Desktop\\MyDatabase.xls");
            WritableWorkbook MASTER1 = Workbook.createWorkbook(f);//MASTER is the name of our database
            WritableSheet History_Table = MASTER1.createSheet("History_Table", 0);//names the first sheet as History_Table
            MASTER1 = Workbook.createWorkbook(f);//makes the Database.xlx writable

            Label L00 = new Label (0,0,"RUN#");
            History_Table.addCell(L00);
            MASTER1.write();
            System.out.println("finished...");
            MASTER1.close();
        } 
        catch (WriteException | IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TryBehaviours.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}
```

}

and this is my Starter class:

```
public class Starter extends Agent {

//int members = 50;

String[] name = new String[10];
AID[] AIDlist = new AID[10];

@Override
protected void setup() {
    for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
        name[i] = "Agent" + (i + 1);
        AIDlist[i] = new AID(name[i], AID.ISLOCALNAME);
    }
    AgentContainer c = getContainerController();
    AgentController[] a = new AgentController[10];
    for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
        try {
            a[j] = c.createNewAgent(name[j], "TryBehaviours", null);
            a[j].start();
            System.out.println(" Created: " + AIDlist[j]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

}
}

2. also, at line `a[j] = c.createNewAgent(name[j], "TryBehaviours", null);` I receive error related to:

   @Override
   public void run() {
       if (target != null) {
           target.run();
       }
   }

what's wrong with my code? .. this Starter class works well for other classes but for this one it causes problems and errors

Comment: first, why is `Workbook.createWorkbook(f)` being called twice?

Comment: yeah, that was a BIG mistake caused by being so careless, I deleted that line, but still problem with class Starter remains.

Comment: When I use this code in Starter, it works and agent Alice writes Run# in cell(0,0):

`String name = "Alice" ;
        AgentContainer c = getContainerController();
        try {
            AgentController a = c.createNewAgent( name, "TryBehaviours", null );
            a.start();
        }
        catch (Exception e){}`

but I want more than one agent to be created and write in excel....

can you help me with this?
@sofend

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with JADE.  That said, the rule of thumbs are: 1) start with something simple that works and 2) incrementally try adding the steps leading up to the feature you desire and see where it breaks (possibly using automated test methods), and 3) RTFM.

Comment: For later reference, I just wanted to point out that this is not related to JADE in any way, this is just a Java matter.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem has to do with the method you call with `MASTER1.write();`.
You probably need to specify an output file for the workbook to write to.